# cannot update game centre leaderboard score

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

currently having problem updating game centre leaderboard score (sandbox).
i have be using this gamemanager class from

http://ganbarugames.com/2011/07/cocos2d-game-center/

I have 2 CCMenuItemSprite button with selector below (HelloWorldLayer)

```
-(void) gamecentreButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

[[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterManager] showLeaderboardForCategory:@"com.sriv.colortrack.survivortopscore" ];

}

-(void) addscoreButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
//usingt this value 78965 for testing
[[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterManager] reportScore:78965 forCategory:@"com.sriv.colortrack.survivortopscore"];

}
```

So far when i click "gamecentreButtonTapped" i can view game centre.
but when i try to update the score by selecting "addscoreButtonTapped" the score is not updated in the leaderboard.
it shows no Score.

what could be the problem? i have waited few hours but still no update. i have attached more code below.

```
//gamecentremanager.m

- (void)reportScore:(int64_t)score forCategory:(NSString *)category
{

    // Create score object
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
     NSLog(@"numbersent=yes");
    scoreReporter.value = score;

    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error != nil)

        {
            [unsentScores addObject:scoreReporter];
        }

    }];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if the local player is not signed in, and if the local player account is not a sandbox account. Check that you have done both.

Comment: hi Ray did not expect you will respond. firstly thanks for the wonderfull work on your tutorials in http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials. Im actually in the sandbox account, i finally got the score after 1 day. but the score is different than i have send. What can cause this wrong score? When i check my NSlog it was a smaller value than the score in game centre, which is 78 965 412. Score so far apart.

Comment: I'm not Ray. I'm this guy: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com  Btw, Game Center will only accept scores that are higher (better) than the previous score for the same player.

Comment: ops sorry. ok as i can remember i never even submitted this score 78 965 412. Thats why im a little lost.